# tf.nn.conv2d occurs InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of uint8 is not in the list of allowed values

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm just studying how to use tensorflow 2.x version.
But my code occurs error, and I don't know the reason.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('dataset/bird_pic_by_benjamin_planche.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
img = tf.constant(img)
img = tf.reshape(img, [1, 680, 608])
img = tf.reshape(img, [1, 680, 608, 1])
parameters = [[1/16, 2/16, 1/16],
             [2/16, 4/16, 2/16],
             [1/16, 2/16, 1/16]]
kernel = tf.constant(parameters)
print("Kernel shape : {}".format(kernel.shape))
kernel = tf.reshape(kernel, [3, 3, 1, 1])
print("Kernel shape : {}".format(kernel.shape))
img = tf.nn.conv2d(img, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

error is

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 img = tf.nn.conv2d(img, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
> 200     try:
> --> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
> 202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
> 203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py
> in conv2d_v2(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations,
> name)    2164                 data_format=data_format,    2165
> dilations=dilations,
> -> 2166                 name=name)    2167     2168
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
> 200     try:
> --> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
> 202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
> 203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py
> in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu,
> data_format, dilations, name, filters)    2272
> data_format=data_format,    2273         dilations=dilations,
> -> 2274         name=name)    2275   return squeeze_batch_dims(    2276       input,
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py
> in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu,
> explicit_paddings, data_format, dilations, name)
> 935       return _result
> 936     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> --> 937       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
> 938     except _core._FallbackException:
> 939       pass
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
> in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    6841   message = e.message +
> (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")    6842   # pylint:
> disable=protected-access
> -> 6843   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)    6844   # pylint: enable=protected-access    6845
>
> c:\users\goeun\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\six.py in
> raise_from(value, from_value)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of uint8 is not in the list
> of allowed values: half, bfloat16, float, double, int32   ; NodeDef:
> {{node Conv2D}}; Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T ->
> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT,
> DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32]; attr=strides:list(int);
> attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true;
> attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID", "EXPLICIT"];
> attr=explicit_paddings:list(int),default=[];
> attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"];
> attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]> [Op:Conv2D]

what is the problem..? Please help me..

Comment: What is the data type of ``img`` tensor?

Comment: it's type is <dtype: 'uint8'>

Comment: So, convert it to float32 to be supported by conv2d. use ``img=tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32)`` before feeding it to the layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your input tensor to a one of supported data type of `tf.nn.conv2d`. Based on the doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d), the supported types are `half, bfloat16, float32, float64`.

Your input tensor (`img`) is in `uint8` format, and is not supported as input data type. So, just convert your tensor before feeding it to the layer:

```
img = tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32)
```